# Haml implement select multiple as in HTML

Tags: haml

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How in Haml can I create a select multiple tag like in HTML? Like the nice helper function of select_tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this

```
%select{:multiple => true}
  %option{value: 'volvo} Volvo
  %option{value: 'saab'} Saab
  %option(value: 'opel'} Opel
  %option{value: 'audi'} Audi
```

You can obviously also use `select_tag`:

```
= select_tag
```

*EDIT*

An even cleaner way to do the above:

```
%select{:multiple => true}
  - ["Volvo", "Saab", "Opel", "Audi"].each do |o|
    %option{value: o.downcase} o
```

Comment: I love Haml. So elegant.